# Close Background Gap on lightning-card

Tags: lightning-web-components

With the advent of the Winter release a gap has appeared between the two top sections of our LWCs which use lightning-card:

[image]

How can we get the gray background to cross the gap?  Code below:

```
<template>
<lightning-card variant="narrow">
    <h1 slot="title" class="slds-page-header headerBaby">
        <lightning-layout vertical-align="center">
            <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:poll" size="small"></lightning-icon>
            <lightning-layout-item padding="horizontal-small" alignment-bump="right">
                <span style="font-size: 15.5px;"><strong>{label.Label_FinancialSummary}</strong></span>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </h1>
    <h1 slot="actions" class="slds-page-header headerBaby">
        <lightning-layout vertical-align="center">
            <lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-combobox options={currencyList} value={loadCurrency} dropdown-alignment="left" variant="label-hidden" class="skinny" 
                                    title={label.Currency} onchange={currencyChangeHandler}></lightning-combobox>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-button-icon variant="border-filled" type="button" icon-name="utility:refresh" size="medium" 
                                       title={label.Refresh} onclick={refreshHandler}></lightning-button-icon>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </h1>....
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing it from a Narrow card to a basic card? Try removing variant="narrow"

See docs.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card/example

Comment: No impact on the issue.